# Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: i is not defined

Tags: node.js

I'm new in Node.js programmation and I need someone for help. I'm developing a web-scraping program and I'm using puppeteer; my problem is that I need a function for counting the number of pharmacy so I'm using the function:

```js
for (let i = 0; i > nombres; i++) {
    const nom = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('div.card-header > a > strong')[`${i}`].innerText);
    console.log(nom)
};
```

and the script say:

> ```
> (node:4016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: i is not defined
> ```

If anyone can help me that would be really nice, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "i" variable is only available to the scope of your function and not to the page.evaluate scope, this can be fixed by passing it on, as follows:

```
const nom = await page.evaluate((i) => document.querySelectorAll('div.card-header > a > strong')[i].innerText, i);
```

Comment: yup, just go ahead and tick the checkmark if it works

Comment: `const nombres = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('div.card-header > a > strong').length);
    console.log(nombres);
    for (let i = 0; i > nombres; i++) {
    var nom = await page.evaluate((i) => document.querySelectorAll('div.card-header > a > strong')[i].innerText);
    console.log(nom)};`
the script do not returning me the "nom" variable, i don't know why.

Comment: forgot to add the return keyword, edited the code again, this should work now!

Comment: `const nombres = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('div.card-header > a > strong').length);
    console.log(nombres);
    for (let i = 0; i > nombres; i++) {
    const nom = await page.evaluate((i) => {return document.querySelectorAll('div.card-header > a > strong')[i].innerText;}, i)
    console.log(nom)};`
The script returning good the "nombres" but the script don't give me the "nom" variable. do you even know why ?